# Where is "The Not-So-Phantom Tollbooth"?

Tags: borderlands-2

I can't find it for the Bloodshot Ramparts challenge:

**The Not-So-Phantom Tollbooth**

> Pay the toll.

[image: challenge]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First 'room'. Which consists of two connected 'rooms'. After you start walk down the ramp, turn right, and see the dividing part between the two rooms. The dividing part between them contains the tollbooth. You would think it is hard to miss, but I also moved past it the first time without seeing it.

When you see it you will see it, it is rather obvious it even has a bar that is down so cars cannot pass without paying. To finish the challenge you do need to pay five credits.

What you are looking for is in fact a normal tollbooth. It is what it says on the tin.

[This wikipage, has a picture.](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Not-So-Phantom_Tollbooth)